# Unexpected token < destroys other site functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm getting this error for this line of code

```
jQuery("body").html(jQuery("body").html().replace(/Some Text/gi, "<strong>Some Text</strong>"));
```

I am just trying to attach a strong tag to every instance of the words "Some Text" across site pages.

But this error actually destroys my other site functionalities, specifically AJAX stuff.

```
Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Further info on error: (anonymous function) @ (index):227
```

Comment: If you take out that call, everything works as normal?

Comment: Is error returned on first or second call ? If called twice would replace `<strong>Some Text</strong>` with `<strong><strong>Some Text</strong></strong>` ? , can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: At first glance, it doesn't appear that anything is wrong with the code you posted. Make sure you're using a JavaScript linter to ensure you can see Syntax errors (among other things). (For example, my favorite editor for client-side JavaScript is Sublime Text and I use https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-jshint)

Comment: The error message **Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <** specifically means that you have a "<" character somewhere in your javascript where it should not be. The code your showing would not cause this issue please see your code working in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7z5uof1/)

Comment: Yes, if I take out this line of code, everything works normally. 

The line number indicates that the error is indeed from that function call. By the way, the code snippet is inside a jQuery(document).ready function

Comment: @guest271314 That still wouldn't cause that error would it? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7z5uof1/1/), there must be a "<" in the javascript somewhere

Comment: It only processes each instance of "Some Text" once, therefore stacking isnt happening here

Comment: Is the function defined inside the `body` tag by chance?

Comment: You shouldn't replace whole contents of the body element. That's madness. Select the target elements and replace contents of those specific elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your function is in your `body` tag.

When you do this...

```
<body>
$(function(){
    jQuery("body").html(jQuery("body").html().replace(/Some Text/gi, "<strong>Some Text</strong>"));
});
</body>
```

You are replacing all instances of 'Some Text' in the **whole body** including the function itself

You could, move your function into your head tag...

**BUT** as @Vohuman pointed out

> "You shouldn't replace whole contents of the body element. That's madness. Select the target elements and replace contents of those specific elements."

### ^^Good advice

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I should have known better. Now replaced the selector with my main div element, #content-area. Now everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

Following suggestion by @Vohuman

> Select the target elements and replace contents of those specific
>   elements.

try utilizing `:contains()` selector `.html(function(index, html){})`

```js
jQuery(":contains(Some Text)").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/Some Text/gi, "<strong>Some Text</strong>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Some Text

<div>Some Text</div>
```